# Is it possible to create your own 3D texture for volumes?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I turn data arrays via python into VDB volumes to import into blender.
[image]

This is a tedious process and I lose the spatial information from the data. With geometry nodes in 3.3 they are adding a volume cube that I can import density information into.

[image]

Is there some way of importing the data into non_mesh locations to then be loaded as a texture or volume grid?
[image]

Currently, for non volume options I store the data into verts but is there some place somewhere else within the datasphere I can store it to input into the volume?